# How do I limit a Mann Kendall test to use the start and end dates if the time series and to use non-NA data?

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I need to run the Mann-Kendall test (package trend in R, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trend/index.html) on varying length time series data. Currently the time series analysis is run with the start year that I manually specify, but that may not be the actual start date. A lot of my sites contain differing start years and some may have different ending years. I condensed my data into the following. This is water quality data, so has issues with missing data and varying start/end dates.

I also deal with NAs in the middle of the time series and at the beginning. I would like to smooth out the missing NAs when in the middle of a time series. If the NAs are at the beginning, I would like to start the time series with the first actual value.

```
+---------+------------+------+--------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| SITE_ID | PROGRAM_ID | YEAR |  ANC_UEQ_L   |  NO3_UEQ_L  |  SO4_UEQ_L  | SBC_ALL_UEQ_L | SBC_NA_UEQ_L |
+---------+------------+------+--------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1992 | 36.12        | 0.8786      | 91.90628571 | 185.5595714   | 156.2281429  |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1993 | 22.30416667  | 2.671258333 | 86.85733333 | 180.5109167   | 154.1934167  |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1994 | 25.25166667  | 3.296475    | 92.00533333 | 184.3589167   | 157.3889167  |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1995 | 23.39166667  | 1.753436364 | 97.58981818 | 184.5251818   | 160.2047273  |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1983 | 4.133333333  | 20          | 134.4333333 | 182.1         | 157.4        |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1984 | 2.6          | 21.85       |      137.78 | 170.67        | 150.64       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1985 | 3.58         | 20.85555556 | 133.7444444 | 168.82        | 150.09       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1986 | -5.428571429 | 40.27142857 |       124.9 | 152.4         | 136.2142857  |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1987 | NA           | 13.75       |      122.75 | 137.4         | 126.3        |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1988 | 4.666666667  | 26.13333333 | 123.7666667 | 174.9166667   | 155.4166667  |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1989 | 6.58         | 31.91       |      124.63 | 167.39        | 148.68       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1990 | 2.354545455  | 39.49090909 | 121.6363636 | 161.6454545   | 144.5545455  |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1991 | 5.973846154  | 30.54307692 | 119.8138462 | 165.4661185   | 147.0807338  |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1992 | 4.174359     | 16.99051285 | 124.1753846 | 148.5505115   | 131.8894862  |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1993 | 6.05         | 19.76125    |    117.3525 | 148.3025      | 131.3275     |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1994 | -2.51666     | 17.47167    |   117.93266 | 129.64167     | 114.64501    |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1995 | 8.00936875   | 22.66188125 |    112.3575 | 166.1220813   | 148.7095813  |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1980 | NA           | NA          |      94.075 | NA            | NA           |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1981 | NA           | NA          |       124.7 | NA            | NA           |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1982 | 33.26666667  | NA          | 73.53333333 | 142.75        | 117.15       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1983 | 26.02        | NA          |        94.9 | 147.96        | 120.44       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1984 | 20.96        | NA          |       82.98 | 137.4         | 110.46       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1985 | 29.325       | 0.157843137 |      84.975 | 144.45        | 118.45       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1986 | 28.6         | 0.88504902  |      81.675 | 139.7         | 114.45       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1987 | 25.925       | 1.065441176 |       74.15 | 131.875       | 108.7        |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1988 | 29.4         | 1.048529412 |      80.625 | 148.15        | 122.5        |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1989 | 27.7         | 0.907598039 |      81.025 | 143.1         | 119.275      |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1990 | 27.4         | 0.642647059 |       77.65 | 126.825       | 104.775      |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1991 | 24.95        | 1.228921569 |        74.1 | 138.55        | 115.7        |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1992 | 29.425       | 0.591911765 |       73.85 | 130.675       | 106.65       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1993 | 22.53333333  | 0.308169935 | 64.93333333 | 117.3666667   | 96.2         |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1994 | 29.93333333  | 0.428431373 | 67.23333333 | 124.0666667   | 101.2333333  |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1995 | 39.33333333  | 0.57875817  | 65.36666667 | 128.8333333   | 105.0666667  |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1987 | 12.39        | 0.65        |       99.48 | 136.37        | 107.75       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1988 | 10.87333333  | 0.69        | 104.6133333 | 131.9         | 105.2        |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1989 | 5.57         | 1.09        |      105.46 | 136.125       | 109.5225     |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1990 | 13.4725      | 0.8975      |      99.905 | 134.45        | 108.9875     |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1991 | 11.3         | 0.805       |     100.605 | 134.3775      | 108.9725     |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1992 | 9.0025       | 7.145       |      99.915 | 136.8625      | 111.945      |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1993 | 7.7925       | 6.6         |      95.865 | 133.0975      | 107.4625     |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1994 | 7.59         | 3.7625      |     97.3575 | 129.635       | 104.465      |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1995 | 7.7925       | 1.21        |      100.93 | 133.9875      | 109.5025     |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1988 | 18.84390244  | 17.21142857 | 228.8684211 | 282.6540541   | 260.5648649  |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1989 | 11.7248      | 21.21363636 | 216.5973451 | 261.3711712   | 237.4929204  |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1990 | 2.368571429  | 35.23448276 | 216.7827586 | 286.0034483   | 264.3137931  |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1991 | 33.695       | 40.733      |      231.92 | 350.91075     | 328.443      |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1992 | 18.49111111  | 26.14818889 |    219.1488 | 301.3785889   | 281.8809222  |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1993 | 17.28181818  | 27.65394545 | 210.6605091 | 290.064       | 271.9205455  |
+---------+------------+------+--------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Here is the code currently that will run time series for my actual data if I change the start year to miss the NAs in the earlier data. It works great for sites that have values for that entire time, but gives me odd results when different start/end years are taken into account.

```
Mann_Kendall_Values_Trimmed <- filter(LTM_Data_StackOverflow_9_22_2020, YEAR >1984) %>% #I manually trimmed the data here to prevent some errors
  group_by(SITE_ID) %>% 
  filter(n() > 2) %>% #filter sites with more than 10 years of data
  gather(parameter, value, SO4_UEQ_L, ANC_UEQ_L, NO3_UEQ_L, SBC_ALL_UEQ_L, SBC_NA_UEQ_L ) %>% 
  #, DOC_MG_L) 
  group_by(parameter, SITE_ID, PROGRAM_ID) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(ts_out = map(data, ~ts(.x$value, start=c(1985, 1), end=c(1995, 1), frequency=1))) %>% 
#this is where I would like to specify the first year in the actual time series with data. End year would also be tied to the last year of data.
  mutate(mk_res = map(ts_out, ~mk.test(.x, alternative = c("two.sided", "greater", "less"),continuity = TRUE)),
         sens = map(ts_out, ~sens.slope(.x, conf.level = 0.95))) %>% 
  #run the Mann-Kendall Test
  mutate(mk_stat = map_dbl(mk_res, ~.x$statistic), 
         p_val = map_dbl(mk_res, ~.x$p.value)
         , sens_slope = map_dbl(sens, ~.x$estimates)
  ) %>% 
  #Pull the parameters we need
  select(SITE_ID, PROGRAM_ID, parameter, sens_slope, p_val, mk_stat) %>% 
  mutate(output = case_when(
  sens_slope == 0 ~ "NC",
  sens_slope > 0 & p_val < 0.05 ~ "INS",
  sens_slope > 0 & p_val > 0.05 ~ "INNS",
  sens_slope < 0 & p_val < 0.05 ~ "DES",
  sens_slope < 0 & p_val > 0.05 ~ "DENS"))
```

1. How do I handle the NAs in the middle of the data?
2. How do I get the time series to automatically start and end on the dates with actual data ? For reference each of the site_id's has the following date ranges (not including NAs):

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
|   1234    |   5678    |       9101        |   1121    |   3812    |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1992-1995 | 1983-1995 | 1982 OR 1985-1995 | 1987-1995 | 1988-1993 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Since the test is rank-based, is smoothing / interpolating the middle values a) helpful, and b) necessary? It seems that smoothing over the internal NAs is simply adding a trend that you're later testing for. And since the test is non-parametric and rank-based, does it make a difference when a point is omitted? If the series is monotonic(ish), the ranks will give the right answer whether you skip a year or not.

Comment: Short version: I believe that omitting the NA values is the most sensible action.

Comment: @Jason I did a deeper dive into the data and it appears all of the missing values occur before 1990, so I removed data before 1990 (this is similar to what we did in our Excel Mann-Kendall tests). Then I was able to reference the code (see answer below) to reference the min and max for .x$YEAR which I wasn't able to do previously because of the groupings of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

To make the data more consistent, I decided to organize the data as individual time-series (grouping by parameter, year, site_id, program) in Oracle before importing into R.

```
+---------+------------+------+--------------+-----------+
| SITE_ID | PROGRAM_ID | YEAR |    Value     | Parameter |
+---------+------------+------+--------------+-----------+
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1992 | 36.12        | ANC       |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1993 | 22.30416667  | ANC       |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1994 | 25.25166667  | ANC       |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1995 | 23.39166667  | ANC       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1990 | 2.354545455  | ANC       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1991 | 5.973846154  | ANC       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1992 | 4.174359     | ANC       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1993 | 6.05         | ANC       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1994 | -2.51666     | ANC       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1995 | 8.00936875   | ANC       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1990 | 27.4         | ANC       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1991 | 24.95        | ANC       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1992 | 29.425       | ANC       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1993 | 22.53333333  | ANC       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1994 | 29.93333333  | ANC       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1995 | 39.33333333  | ANC       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1990 | 13.4725      | ANC       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1991 | 11.3         | ANC       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1992 | 9.0025       | ANC       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1993 | 7.7925       | ANC       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1994 | 7.59         | ANC       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1995 | 7.7925       | ANC       |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1990 | 2.368571429  | ANC       |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1991 | 33.695       | ANC       |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1992 | 18.49111111  | ANC       |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1993 | 17.28181818  | ANC       |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1992 | 0.8786       | NO3       |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1993 | 2.671258333  | NO3       |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1994 | 3.296475     | NO3       |
|    1234 | Alpha      | 1995 | 1.753436364  | NO3       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1990 | 39.49090909  | NO3       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1991 | 30.54307692  | NO3       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1992 | 16.99051285  | NO3       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1993 | 19.76125     | NO3       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1994 | 17.47167     | NO3       |
|    5678 | Beta       | 1995 | 22.66188125  | NO3       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1990 | 0.642647059  | NO3       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1991 | 1.228921569  | NO3       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1992 | 0.591911765  | NO3       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1993 | 0.308169935  | NO3       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1994 | 0.428431373  | NO3       |
|    9101 | Victor     | 1995 | 0.57875817   | NO3       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1990 | 0.8975       | NO3       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1991 | 0.805        | NO3       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1992 | 7.145        | NO3       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1993 | 6.6          | NO3       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1994 | 3.7625       | NO3       |
|    1121 | Charlie    | 1995 | 1.21         | NO3       |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1990 | 35.23448276  | NO3       |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1991 | 40.733       | NO3       |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1992 | 26.14818889  | NO3       |
|    3812 | Charlie    | 1993 | 27.65394545  | NO3       |
+---------+------------+------+--------------+-----------+
```

Once in R, I was able to edit the code to the following with the beginning of the code. Remaining code was the same.

```
Mann_Kendall_Values_Trimmed <- filter(LTM_Data_StackOverflow_9_22_2020, YEAR >1989, PARAMETER != 'doc') %>% 
  #filter data to start in 1990 as this removes nulls from pre-1990 sampling
  group_by(SITE_ID) %>% 
  filter(n() > 10) %>% #filter sites with more than 10 years of data
  #gather(SITE_ID, PARAMETER, VALUE) #I believe this is now redundant %>% 
  group_by(PARAMETER, SITE_ID, PROGRAM_ID) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(ts_out = map(data, ~ts(.x$VALUE, start=c(min(.x$YEAR), 1), c(max(.x$YEAR), 1), frequency=1)))
```

This achieved the result I needed for all time series that have sufficient length (greater than 2 I believe) to run the mann-kendall test. The parameter that had those issues will be dealt with in separate R code.